# Why do the New York Special Flight Rule (SPFR) and Skyline routes exist simultaneously?

Tags: general-aviation

If I understand correctly Skyline just allows you to fly 1300-2000 ft, while SFRA allows you fly surface to 1300 ft.

The question is, why there are 2 airspaces like this? Why can SPFR not cover surface all the way to 2000 ft?